# send List through PHP to MYSQL in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-activity, android-service

I built an android application, the application contain SQLite DB, i need when the user open the application a service run in background to compare the values in local SQlite with the data in MYSQL (Hosted externally), the comparision will based on status value, so the i took the ID and Status from the local SQlite and compare it with cloud data, if the Status value in cloud more than the status in local it mean that the data was changed so the application will update the local data.
Now i am wrote below code to get the ID and Status from local SQLite:

```
private void get_local_cloud_compare() {
          data= new DataHandler(this);
             data.open();
             Cursor bcreturneddata = data.returndata();
             if(bcreturneddata.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do
                    {
        IDslist.add(bcreturneddata.getString(0));// 0 position for ID
        Statuslist.add(bcreturneddata.getString(8));// 8'th position for status
                    }while(bcreturneddata.moveToNext());

                    }

             data.close();
    }
```

now usually when i need to communicate with MYSQL database i used the below code:

```
private void checkchanges(// argument here ) {


     InputStream isr = null;
    String result = null;
    try
    {
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new  HttpPost("here the url of my php file");   
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(here ArrayList<NameValuePair>));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
isr = entity.getContent();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
try 
{
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);                  
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
{
sb.append(line +"\n");
}
isr.close();
result = sb.toString();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
try
{
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(result);
for ( int i =0; i<jarray.length();i++)
{
JSONObject json = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
//here i read the new received data
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Now in this line: httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(here ArrayList)); how i can pass the two lists IDslist and statuslist instead on namevaluepair ?

and how will be the code of PHP file that will take the IDs list and download data to compare it locally, i just need to know how to download the data from MYSQL based on IDslist instead of namevaluepair since there is no exact number of rows in local DB ?

Comment: `how i can pass the two lists IDslist and statuslist instead on namevaluepair `. No. You pass an ArrayList there. But before that you have made an ArrayList of <NameValuePair>'s. Add all items in your lists in two loops with `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idslist" + nr, IDslist.get(nr)));` and so on.

Comment: but how i can do this if the number of items is not static, means in the PHP file how i will read the data since i didn't now the number of rows

Comment: There are several options. You could send a name value pair` "listcount", listcount` first. Or just make a loop where you use the function isset() to check if $_REQUEST['idslist + nr'] exists/isset.

Comment: ok great but how i can read it in PHP file, assume i send 5 ID's how i can select all data related to these ID ?

Comment: That i already told you. Read my last comment again.